# I want to update my range slider to 10% on clicking anywhere on it. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html

I've a range slider and I want to update it only 10% on clicking anywhere on this. Right now if I am clicking on end of the range slider it takes to 100% of its value.

Is there any possibility to do this? I have tried this:

Markup:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="0" max="50" value="24.5" step="1" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var output = document.getElementById('range');
output.innerHTML = $('#slider').val();

function showValue(newValue) {
    output.innerHTML = newValue;
}

$('#slider').change(function(e) {
    showValue($(this).val());

});
```

Please refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/6HdvB/)

Comment: I note that you've tagged you question with both JQuery and AngularJS. Ideally you shouldn't be using both on the same project unless there's very good reason to. AngularJS should take care of all the DOM manipulation you need.

Comment: Show us some code, both in your question and perhaps using http://jsfiddle.net/ too.

Comment: Please tell us what is the "range slider" you are using (with a link for example)

Comment: Sorry for that, but I want it to be done in any of these platforms.

Comment: here this the code http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/6HdvB/

Comment: You want to update by 10% but it should be add or deduct accordingly to your click, right? or you just want to add only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand correctly your question but if you want on click on the slider tag this is increased o decreased by 10(depends you click left o right of cursor)
Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/HMNW5/2/)
All jQuery code you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".no" ).on('mousedown',function(){return false;});   
    $('#slider').click(function(e){
        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var val=parseInt($('#slider').val())
        x>val?valx=val+=10:valx=val-=10
        $('#slider').val(valx)
        $('#range').text(valx)
        })

})
</script>
```

I don't know why this code doesn't work showing the fiddle page in IE11, but i test this code online on my site and works also with IE11
If this solution suits your needs remeber to vote up;)
Thanks

Comment: can it be done with angular as well? If yes, can you please create me a fiddle? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question, could be this what you want?

```
$('#slider').click(function(e) {
    $('#slider').val(10);
    showValue(10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Fiddle below, hope this could be the requirement.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bd8v/)

```
 $(function() {
 $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
 range: "max",
 min: 0,
 max: 100,
 step: 10,
 value:10,
 slide: function( event, ui ) {
  $( "#count" ).val( ui.value );
 }
});
  $( "#count" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
});

<p>
 <label for="count">Steps Count : </label>
 <input type="text" id="count" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-range-max"></div>
```

Cheers :)